# Pynetdicom: Compiled app (exe) can't connect to the PACS-server

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, pynetdicom

I've created an application, that connect to PACS server and Downloaded Studies. Application perfectly work, when i run it from python. But when i create an exe, using pyinstaller - created exe loses the ability to connect to server. log:"Unable to connect to remote".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd found out what is the problem! An issue associate with pynetdicom 2.0.0 version. I wrote programm using pynetdicom 1.5.7. And this version works well. But i can't compile the program on PC (too long story to explain why), where i wrote the programm using pyinstaller, so i had to use another computer, where i downloaded all code and install all libriaries i need. So, in the another computer "pip" installed last version of pynedicom (on that moment it was 2.0.0). When i downgraded to version 1.5.7. - the programm start working well.